# Im getting publish errors for PXDefault in code below

Tags: c#, acumatica

I have checked all the braces and the syntax for the code and this is the only code getting published. I have removed everything else

```
using PX.Objects;
using PX.Data;

namespace MaxQ.Products.RBRR
{
  public class ContractMaint_Extension : PXGraphExtension<ContractMaint>
  {
    #region Event Handlers
   
    protected virtual void XRBContrHdr_DestSiteID_CacheAttached(PXCache cache)
      {   
         [PXDefault(typeof(Search2<INSite.siteCD,
          InnerJoin<BAccount, On<BAccount.bAccountID, Equal<Current<XRBContrHdr.bAccountID>>>,
          InnerJoin<LocationExtAddress, On<LocationExtAddress.locationID, Equal<BAccount.defLocationID>>>>,
          Where<INSite.siteID, Equal<LocationExtAddress.cSiteID>>>), PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
      }
      
    #endregion
  }
}
```

the error Im getting is

> \App_RuntimeCode\ContractMaint.cs(13): error CS1513: } expected
>
> \App_RuntimeCode\ContractMaint.cs(18): error CS1519: Invalid token '}' in class, struct, or Interface member declaration
>
> \App_RuntimeCode\ContractMaint.cs(22): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected
>
> \App_RuntimeCode\ContractMaint.cs(13): error CS1513: } expected

Comment: The `[PXDefault]` attribute needs to have something to 'apply' to - i.e. a property, field or method.

Comment: Thank You.  that was it had it inside the method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error messages point to a malformed block `{}` in the source code:
[image]

This occurs because the attributes need to placed before the method to decorate the method:

```
[PXDefault(…)]
protected virtual void XRBContrHdr_DestSiteID_CacheAttached(PXCache cache)
{
}
```

In your code the attributes are placed within the method definition which is not valid in C#:

```
protected virtual void XRBContrHdr_DestSiteID_CacheAttached(PXCache cache)
{
   [PXDefault(…)]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case of a cache attached method the attributes are defined on the method, you also need to specify the "overwrite" method for the attributes on the field. Therefore a working example would be

```
[PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Append)]    
[PXDefault(typeof(Search2<INSite.siteCD,
      InnerJoin<BAccount, On<BAccount.bAccountID, Equal<Current<XRBContrHdr.bAccountID>>>,
      InnerJoin<LocationExtAddress, On<LocationExtAddress.locationID, Equal<BAccount.defLocationID>>>>,
      Where<INSite.siteID, Equal<LocationExtAddress.cSiteID>>>), PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
virtual void XRBContrHdr_DestSiteID_CacheAttached(PXCache cache) {}
```

[This](https://help-2019r2.acumatica.com/(W(8))/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=b78b0a53-b9db-0693-66fa-7d2b432b9f38) help document will explain more about the PXMergeAttributes Attribute

Comment: PXMergeAttributes can be omitted, in which case it will use the default Replace mode. From documentation: forces the system to use custom attributes instead of the existing ones. This option is used by default if you do not specify the PXMergeAttributes attribute on the customized field.